# Report design issues with receipt paper

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a report in Crystal Reports that runs and works great. However, there is an issue that I am facing. Right now, it runs, prints the patient copy, blank section, and then office copy of a purchase receipt. The problem is this all printers on one sheet of paper to an Epson thermal printer before it cuts. Then we have to tear between the two copies to give the customer theirs and keep ours. What I would like to find out is if there is a way to simulate 2 reports in one. So the out come would be this: prints customer copy, cuts the paper, prints the office copy.

I have attached a screen shot of how it is current set up and wanted to see if anyone had some suggestions on how I could possibly get the result I want without telling it to run 2 reports.

Thanks for any and all help.

Current Report Design

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of me it may not possible. You have to give separate print command to thermal printer. E.g. Pass the parameter as Patient Copy and Print it. again call & print the same report with pass the parameter as Office Copy. Hope by doing this it will solve your problem.